# Change axis variables on $xy$ graph

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs

All I want to do is change the variables on this axis.  I don't need to add any labels, just change $x$ and $y$ to $M$ and $N$, for instance.

```
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage{pgfplots,wrapfig}

\begin{document}
\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0pt}
     \begin{tikzpicture}
          \tkzInit[xmax=6,ymax=6,xmin=-1,ymin=-3]
          \tkzGrid
          \tkzAxeXY
     \end{tikzpicture}
\end{wrapfigure}
\end{document}
```

Does anybody have a quick fix?  Thanks in advance.

[image: Output]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this do the job?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage{pgfplots,wrapfig}

\begin{document}
\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0pt}
     \begin{tikzpicture}
          \tkzInit[xmax=6,ymax=6,xmin=-1,ymin=-3]
          \tkzGrid
          \tkzAxeX[label=$M$]
          \tkzAxeY[label=$N$]
     \end{tikzpicture}
\end{wrapfigure}
\end{document}
```

[image]