# TikZ labels are drawn on every tick

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex, tkz-euclide, bugtracking

I executed the exact same code that was posted here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/334718/166582
But my result is different, I have no idea why the labels are repeated. As reference the code is

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage{pgfplots,wrapfig}

\begin{document}
\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0pt}
     \begin{tikzpicture}
          \tkzInit[xmax=6,ymax=6,xmin=-1,ymin=-3]
          \tkzGrid
          \tkzAxeX[label=$M$]
          \tkzAxeY[label=$N$]
     \end{tikzpicture}
\end{wrapfigure}
\end{document}
```

I'm running pdflatex from the docker container `texlive/texlive:latest`. So it's up to date. Is this a bug, or did I make a mistake somewhere?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I already saw something like this here.
It seems to be kind of a bug since a recent version of `tkz-euclide`, if Alain comes by, he should be able to give some explanation.

One way to correct this is to do the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage{pgfplots,wrapfig}

\begin{document}
\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0pt}
     \begin{tikzpicture}
          \tkzInit[xmax=6,ymax=6,xmin=-1,ymin=-3]
          \tkzGrid
          \tkzAxeX[label={}]
          \tkzDrawX[label=$M$]
          \tkzAxeY[label={}]
          \tkzDrawY[label=$N$]
     \end{tikzpicture}
\end{wrapfigure}
\end{document}
```

[image: pgfplot axis label]